# How do I add custom headers to a failed message before it reaches the dead letter topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring cloud stream app using kafka as my message broker. I'm not using any `KStream`s just functions that return a `Consumer<MyClass>`. Like this:

```java
  @Bean
  public Consumer<MyEventType> myConsumerFunction() {
    return value -> {
        doStuff(value)
    };
  }
```

I've set up the bindings to send failed messages to a dead letter topic using the following configs:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          myConsumerFunction-in-0:
            consumer:
              enable-dlq: true
              dlq-name: my-dlt-name
```

If a message fails I want to add a header to the message before it reaches the DLT. Something like `x-processAttemptCount`. Then I want to consume it from the DLT, check the `x-processAttemptCount` and if it's below a threshold I want to send it back to the original topic. I want to repeat this process until `x-processAttemptCount` gets too high then I'll log the message and drop it.

I can't figure out how to add headers to the message. I tried adding headers before the message even fails by calling `Message.getHeaders()` and then `MessageHeaders.put()` but `MessageHeaders` are immutable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to disable the DLQ at the binder level and, instead, use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to configure the container with a `DefaultErrorHandler` with an appropriate `BackOff` and a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

See `addHeadersFunction` on the DLPR:

```java
/**
 * Add a function which will be called to obtain additional headers to add to the
 * published record. Functions are called in the order that they are added, and after
 * any function passed into {@link #setHeadersFunction(BiFunction)}. If a
 * {@link Header} returned is an instance of {@link SingleRecordHeader}, then that
 * header will replace any existing header of that name, rather than being appended as
 * a new value.
 * @param headersFunction the headers function.
 * @since 2.8.4
 * @see #setHeadersFunction(BiFunction)
 */
public void addHeadersFunction(BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, Headers> headersFunction) {
```